# How to retrieve user selected indices from listbox on PDF using itextsharp?

Tags: pdf, listbox, itext

I have listbox on PDF.

User will select multiple options from listbox.

I need to upload PDF to database.

I am unable to retrieve  selected indices from listbox using iTextSharp? 
I tried with

```
SetListSelection("listbox", PreviousExport.ToArray) but no luck.
```

How to retrieve user selected indices from listbox on PDF using itextsharp?

Code from comments:

I am using below code to load listbox .. This is from database

```
form.SetListOption("ddlNoteStatus", strbuilderExport.ToArray, strbuilderDisplay.ToArray)
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ddlNoteStatus", "3")
```

I am able to retrieve other fields from pdf which are not of listbox with below code. But if I use same code for list box only last value selected from list box shows but not all values selected by user

```
stamper.AcroFields.GetField("txtDateFollow")
```

Comment: You say you're unable to retrieve but you're also using a `set` method which is for setting a value. Did you try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3367973/231316

Comment: I am using below code to load listbox .. This is from database

Comment: form.SetListOption("ddlNoteStatus", strbuilderExport.ToArray, strbuilderDisplay.ToArray)
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("ddlNoteStatus", "3")

Comment: I am able to retrieve other fields from pdf which are not of listbox withe below code . But if i use same code for list box only last value selected from list box shows ... but not all values selected by user        ....                  stamper.AcroFields.GetField("txtDateFollow")

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`GetField`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) you want to use [`GetListSelection`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getListSelection%28java.lang.String%29). To be safe, you might want to always call [`GetFieldType`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getFieldType%28java.lang.String%29) to determine the type of field that you're looking at. The below code shows this off:

```
using (var r = new PdfReader(testFile)) {
    var acro = r.AcroFields;
    if(acro.GetFieldType("countries") == AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST ){
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", acro.GetListSelection("countries").ToArray()));
    }
}
```

I tested the above code against a PDF that I created using the below code:

```
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));

            var dd = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 500, 200, 550), "countries");
            dd.Choices = new string[] { "United States", "Canada", "France" };
            dd.ChoiceExports = new string[] { "US", "CA", "FR" };
            dd.Options = dd.Options | TextField.MULTISELECT;
            dd.ChoiceSelections = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 2 });
            writer.AddAnnotation(dd.GetListField());
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sry for late reply.Thanks so much. worked very. YOU saved lot of time. Need to run one more test.. After signing the PDF using acrobat 11 reader,,,,,,,,,,is it possible to retrieve fields .after PDF flattenned.

Comment: Hi Chris,  I tried to get information from PDF after signature using acrobat 11.0 sign option.

Comment: But unable to retrieve information after pdf signed. My requirement,,,,after user signs the document, need to retrieve information from PDF. Is there any option to read the data....

Comment: ChoiceSelections is also the only way i could find to set the lookup value of the combobox in codebehind.